# Must a Boss use their Level Up ability?

Tags: boss-monster

Most Level Up abilities clearly benefit the Boss, but Robobo's is:

> Each opponent mush choose and destroy one Room in his or her Dungeon.

The opponents get to destroy a room (often quite beneficial), and Robobo doesn't!

Is there any way - short of only building a four room dungeon - that Robobo can avoid using this ability? What play strategies can Robobo use to maximize his Level Up ability?

Answer (score 5):

According to the [rules](http://brotherwisegames.com/rules), your boss's "Level Up" ability is *triggered* when your dungeon is 5 rooms in size. "Triggering" implies necessity. So yes, the only way to avoid levelling up is by not building a fifth room.

Secondly, and more to your concern... according to the Advanced Rules (see the entry for Robobo in the glossary using the link above), using Robobo's level up **does not trigger the "destroy this Room" ability for the destroyed room.**