# Does Lady Vix's Level Up force her to lose her current face-up Item?

Tags: boss-monster

Last night, while trying out the expansions for Boss Monster, my opponent triggered Lady Vix's Level Up ability and stole my Cheat Code. However, she already had a face-up card that she wanted to keep face-up (she mainly wanted to *take* Cheat Code from me, not use it for herself). This is where a discrepancy came up.

According to Lady Vix's Level Up, she must take a face-up Item Card and place it face-up in her scorekeeping area, but there is nothing explicitly stating that she is able to have two Item Cards face-up as a result. In contrast, the additional Boss monster for the Alien Artifact treasure in this expansion has a Level Up that *explicitly* states he is able to have two face-up Item Cards for the remainder of the game, so this seems like an ability unique to him.

[image: Lady Vix]

> **Lady Vix**
>   Bandit Queen
>   **Level Up:** Take a face-up Item from a Hero in town or another player. Place it face up in your scorekeeping area.

When Lady Vix's Level Up is triggered and the player is [forced](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/18864/19315) to take an Item Card, is the player *also* forced to turn their existing face-up Item Card face down to make room for the stolen Item Card? Or is the player able to use two Item Cards during that turn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a player has two Item cards face-up in their scoring area and no ability allowing more than one, the player chooses which one to turn face-down.

See the image of the Tools Of Hero Kind expansion rules [here](http://bossmonster.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Items), which says in parenthetical

> You choose which item to keep face-up

when speaking of a player with more than one face-up Item card.